# Map bpmn to wsdl

Tags: wsdl, bpel, bpmn

My task is to take a bpmn 2.0 xml file and map it as good as possible (with a certain error rate) to available web services. For example when my bpmn file explains the process of buying a pizza, i give 10€ and get back 1 pizza. Now it should map that bpmn to the webservice that needs an  of type int with the name "money" etc.

How is that even possible? I searched for a few hours now and came up with the following:

1. I found https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-platform and can easily use it to parse a plain .bpmn file to a java object structure which i can then query. Easy.
2. After parsing the xml notation i should analyze it and search for elements that input data and elements that output data for this are the only things i can map to wsdl (wsdl only describes the structure of the webservice: names of variables, types of variables, number of variables). Problem: I do not find any 1:1 elements i can easily declare as "when this bpmn element is used, it 100% means that the process is getting some input named x". What should i do here? What can i map?
3. I found ws-bpel. As far as i understand i can somehow transfer bpmn to ws-bpel which should be better modeling of the process and more easily be mappable to a wsdl (?). Camunda however doesn't offer this functionality and i am restricted to open source software.

Any suggestions what i should do?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little on what you are trying to achieve and why? I mean, how is this mapping going to be used?

Comment: @It won't be used for anything. This is just a normal task in my studies i have to finish...

Comment: The BPMN specification describes how to map BPMN 2.0 XML to BPEL: http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/2.0/PDF, chapter 14 (page 445/ 475 in PDF ff).